# convert a dictionary in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dictionary where each item is 1D python array and I would like to convert it into a 2D numpy array.

For example, my dictionary is

```
a = {"tom": np.random.uniform(size = 100), "bill": np.random.uniform(size=100)}
```

and I would like to store in a 2D numpy array with shape (100,2).
Have you any suggestions?

Comment: There are various ways of combining a list or tuple of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack the values:

```
np.stack(a.values(), axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) the values:

```
np.column_stack(a.values()).shape
# (100, 2)
```